# insert a character between instance of two characters

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, tr

I have a csv file with X amount of lines in the following format

```
P26439,341,P,L,,P26439,,-0.41
```

where everytime there is a double comma i.e. `,,` I want to insert the word NA in between them so it would appear as `,NA,`

would anyone have a sed, tr, perl or awk solution?

I know that I can replace a character using tr in the following way:

```
tr ",," ",NA,"
```

however this replaces any instance of a comma.

Comment: tr only replaces single characters.  for example, `tr abc ABC` changes any a, b, or c to upper case

Comment: Can you not have an empty field at the start or end of a line too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the possibility for sequential missing fields you will need to do:

```
$ cat file
P26439,341,P,L,,P26439,,-0.41
P26439,341,P,L,,,P26439,,-0.41
P26439,341,P,L,,,,P26439,,-0.41

$ sed ':a;s/,,/,NA,/;ta' file
P26439,341,P,L,NA,P26439,NA,-0.41
P26439,341,P,L,NA,NA,P26439,NA,-0.41
P26439,341,P,L,NA,NA,NA,P26439,NA,-0.41
```

Comment: that is a good point. have just noticed this problem when using the first answer on here

Comment: What means `:a` and `ta` iiSeymour ?

Comment: @sputnick it's [conditional branching](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-6-examples-for-sed-branching-operation/)

Comment: assuming the NA is not for first and last field (as the request mention so ok)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
sed 's/,,/,NA,/g' file.csv
```

[tr](/questions/tagged/tr) is for just one character at a time.

And if you want to edit the file *in place*, add the `-i` switch :

```
sed -i.bak 's/,,/,NA,/g' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
$ echo "P26439,341,P,L,,P26439,,-0.41" | perl -pe 's/,,/,NA,/g'
P26439,341,P,L,NA,P26439,NA,-0.41
```

Comment: You might want to add a little more explanation here-- this answer was flagged by the system as "low quality"

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':cycle
s/,,/,NA/g;t cycle
s/^,/NA,/;s/,$/,NA/' YourFile
```

- set NA for any field, including first and last.
- The cycle is needed for multiple following occurance `,,,` where only the first `,,` is treated at first cycle leaving the second (and any other multitple of 2 occurences) unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Through `awk`:

```
awk -F',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="") $i="NA" }1' OFS=','  file
```

- Replace each empty fields in first,middle,last or if it was multiple occurrences with `NA` string.

#### Input:

```
,P26439,341,P,L,,P26439,,-0.41
P26439,341,P,L,,P26439,,-0.41
P26439,341,P,L,,P26439,,-0.41,
P26439,341,P,L,,,,P26439,,-0.41
```

#### Output:

```
NA,P26439,341,P,L,NA,P26439,NA,-0.41
P26439,341,P,L,NA,P26439,NA,-0.41
P26439,341,P,L,NA,P26439,NA,-0.41,NA
P26439,341,P,L,NA,NA,NA,P26439,NA,-0.41
```